# com.docker.cli.exe: Access is denied in windows

Tags: docker

I am getting ***Access is denied*** error while using docker in windows pro.
I have tried a lot to fix it but in vain. Tried with the latest version and also with the previous version.
Please help.

```
C:\Users\gaurabk>docker --version
fork/exec C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\com.docker.cli.exe: Access is denied.

C:\Users\gaurabk>docker
fork/exec C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\com.docker.cli.exe: Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 1):

after I move my docker from 'c' to 'd' by windows command mklink, I met this:

```
$ docker compose up -d
fork/exec C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\com.docker.cli.exe: Access is denied.
```

I think this is just file permissions problem, so give all permissions to `C:\Program Files\Docker` to all users. And it works after I repeat this action serveral times

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot offer an answer. But, I may have a related issue. Well, at least I have a better understanding of where my issue is coming from.  When I do "docker --version" from my Windows command prompt or Git Bash, the command launches a new window and I'm unable to see the results because the window closes immediately after the command finishes. My problem potentially started after some Window updates were pushed. I had 2.3.0 when the problem started and I've tried with 2.4.0.0 and 2.5.0.0.

[UPDATE 1/12/2021] - I was able to move past my problem by two changes:
(1) Using the Dashboard, I disabled "Enable CLI experimental features" and "Enable cloud experience" which both seem to involve a CLI

After a restart, a "docker run" resulted in "docker-credential-desktop.exe" opening up a blank window. I searched and found: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6652#issuecomment-662960874

I viewed my ~/.docker/config.json and discovered there were two entries:

"credStore": "desktop",
"credsStore": "desktop",

So, as suggested in the link, I changed "credsStore" to "_credsStore" and now docker from the command line is working!